# Testing for Equivalency of Dynamic Arrays (no std::vector!)

Tags: c++, class, dynamic-arrays

I am currently working with dynamic arrays without the use of vector. The program completes different actions on the array class object through a menu. All of the actions seem to work except when testing for equivalency after I copy the first dynamic array (stack1) to a second dynamic array (stack2) of the same capacity. In this scenario, it will state that the two stacks are equivalent even though they are not. For example, the console will output the following when stack 1 is empty and stack 2 contains elements:

[image]

I am unsure if this is a problem with my equality operator or assignment operator. My .h file, .cpp file, and main driver file are included below.

h file:

```
#include <iostream>

class DoubleStack
{
    public:
    
    DoubleStack(size_t capacity); //Constructor

    DoubleStack(const DoubleStack& rhs); //Copy Cosntructor

    ~DoubleStack(void); //Destructor

    DoubleStack& operator=(DoubleStack& rhs); //Assignment operator overload

    int push(double& item); //Add double to top of stack

    int pop(double& item); //Remove top double from stack

    int empty(void); //Check to see if stack is empty

    size_t capacity(void); //Check capacity of stack

    size_t size(void); //Check number of elements on stack

    int operator==(DoubleStack& rhs); //Comparison operator for two stacks
    
    friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &output, const DoubleStack& s); //Operator overload for ostream <<

    private:

    double *data; //pointer for dynamic stack
    size_t stack_size; //Capacity of the stack
    size_t tos; //Top of stack. 0 == empty stack
    size_t noi; //Number of elements on stack
```

.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dblstk.h"

//Constructor & Copy Constructor
DoubleStack::DoubleStack(size_t capacity)
{
    data = new double[capacity]();
    stack_size = capacity;
    tos = 0;
    noi = 0;
}

DoubleStack::DoubleStack(const DoubleStack& rhs)
{
    data = rhs.data;
    stack_size = rhs.stack_size;
    tos = rhs.tos;
    noi = rhs.noi;
}

//Destructor
DoubleStack::~DoubleStack(void)
{
    delete[] data;
}

//Overload for comparison operator
int DoubleStack::operator==( DoubleStack& rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++)
    {
    if (data[i] == rhs.data[i])
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
    }
}

//Assignment operator overload
DoubleStack& DoubleStack::operator=(DoubleStack& rhs)
{                                                   
    delete[] data;
    data = new double[rhs.stack_size];
    stack_size = rhs.stack_size;
    tos = rhs.tos;
    for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++)        
    {
        data[i] = rhs.data[i];
    };
    return *this;                               
}

//ostream operator overload
 std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream &output, const DoubleStack& s)
 {
     for (int i = 0; i<s.tos; i++)
     {
        if (i > 0)
        {
            output << ", ";
        }
        output << s.data[i];
     };
     return output;
 }

//DoubleStack functions
DoubleStack::push(double& item)
{
    if (noi >= stack_size)
    {
        std::cout<<"Stack size at capacity. Cannot push."<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        noi++;
        data[tos++] = item;
        std::cout<<"Inserted "<<item<<std::endl;
        return 1;
    }
}

DoubleStack::pop(double& item)
{
    if (DoubleStack::empty() == true)
    {
        std::cout<<"Cannot remove number because stack is empty."<<std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        noi--;
        data[tos] = item;
        data[tos--];
        std::cout<<"Removed "<<data[tos]<<std::endl;
        return item;
        return 1;
    }
}

DoubleStack::empty(void)
{
    if (noi == 0)
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}

size_t DoubleStack::capacity(void)
{
    return stack_size;
}

size_t DoubleStack::size(void)
{
    return noi;
}
```

main file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "dblstk.h"
#include "stack_driver.cpp"

//Menu function
void Menu()
{
    std::cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"\t \t Welcome to the Stackhouse. \t \t"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"-----------------------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"1. Display Stack 1"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"2. Place a double value onto the top of stack 1"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"3. Remove a value from the top of stack 1"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"4. Check the total capacity of stack 1"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"5. Check current number of items on stack 1"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"6. Copy stack 1 to stack 2"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"7. Check to see if the two stacks are equal"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"8. Quit"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Enter menu selection: "<<std::endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    DoubleStack stack1(10);
    DoubleStack stack2(10);
    Menu();
    int user_input;
    std::string answer;
    do
    {
    std::cout<<"Select an option (1-8)"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>user_input;
    switch (user_input)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            std::cout<<"Displaying stack 1:"<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<stack1<<std::endl;   
            break;
        }
        case 2: 
        {
            std::cout<<"Enter number to push: "<<std::endl;
            double push_item;
            std::cin>>push_item;
            stack1.push(push_item);
            break;
        }
        case 3:
        {
            std::cout<<"Popped top number from stack."<<std::endl;
            double pop_item;
            stack1.pop(pop_item);
            break;
        }
        case 4:
        {
            std::cout<<"The capacity of stack 1 is: "<<stack1.capacity()<<std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case 5:
        {
            std::cout<<"The current number of items on stack 1 is: "<<stack1.size()<<std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case 6:
        {
            std::cout<<"Copying stack 1 to stack 2..."<<std::endl;
            stack2 = stack1;
            std::cout<<"Stack 1 is: "<<stack1<<std::endl;
            std::cout<<"Stack 2 is: "<<stack2<<std::endl;
            break;
        }
        case 7:
        {
            std::cout<<"Checking to see if the two stacks are equal.."<<std::endl;
            if (stack1 == stack2)
            {
                std::cout<<"The stacks are the same!"<<std::endl;
                std::cout<<"Stack 1 is: "<<stack1<<std::endl;
                std::cout<<"Stack 2 is: "<<stack2<<std::endl;
            }
            else
            {
                std::cout<<"The stacks are not the same!"<<std::endl;
                std::cout<<"Stack 1 is: "<<stack1<<std::endl;
                std::cout<<"Stack 2 is: "<<stack2<<std::endl;
            }
            break;
        }
        case 8:
        {
            std::cout<<"Leaving the Stackhouse. Quitting..."<<std::endl;
            return 0;
            break;
        }
        default:
        { 
            std::cout<<"Inavlid."<<std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
    std::cout<<"Press either F/f to continue"<<std::endl;
    std::cin>>answer;
    }
    while (answer == "F" || answer == "f");
}
```

Comment: Your loop always ends after comparing first element. And you never check if there are any elements in the DoubleStack, if one of them is shorter or not...

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example. And do not include code or output in screenshots in your questions. Just use text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equality operator is bugged. Think about what equality means. Two array are equal if **all** the items are equal, but they are not equal if **any** of the items are not equal. But that's not what the code for you equality operator says because you decide whether they are equal or not equal after looking at the **first item only**.

```
//Overload for comparison operator
int DoubleStack::operator==( DoubleStack& rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] == rhs.data[i])
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Here's a partly fixed version

```
//Overload for comparison operator
int DoubleStack::operator==( DoubleStack& rhs)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] != rhs.data[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

See the difference. As soon as I find one not equal number I return false, but I don't return true until I've checked all the numbers.

There is one other fix needed. Two arrays are never equal if their sizes are different. Here's version that checks for that as well.

```
//Overload for comparison operator
int DoubleStack::operator==( DoubleStack& rhs)
{
    // check if same size
    if (size() != rhs.size())
        return false;
    for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++)
    {
        if (data[i] != rhs.data[i])
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

**EDIT**

Here's another bug.

//Assignment operator overload

```
DoubleStack& DoubleStack::operator=(DoubleStack& rhs)
{                                                   
    delete[] data;
    data = new double[rhs.stack_size];
    stack_size = rhs.stack_size;
    tos = rhs.tos;
    for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++)        
    {
        data[i] = rhs.data[i];
    };
    return *this;                               
}
```

This assignment operator fails to copy the `noi` value. It should be

```
DoubleStack& DoubleStack::operator=(DoubleStack& rhs)
{                                                   
    delete[] data;
    data = new double[rhs.stack_size];
    stack_size = rhs.stack_size;
    tos = rhs.tos;
    noi = rhs.noi; ///////// new line ere
    for (int i = 0; i < tos; i++)        
    {
        data[i] = rhs.data[i];
    };
    return *this;                               
}
```

Now the `operator==` should work as well (because it uses `noi` to compare sizes).

But think about this. Since in your code `tos` and `noi` always have the same value, what is the point of having both? It's just leads to possible bugs. You should eliminate one of them.

Comment: Suggestion: Change `int` to `bool` and add `const` to make it `bool DoubleStack::operator==(const DoubleStack& rhs) const`

Comment: thanks! This seems to work when both stacks are empty as it will return that they are the same. However, if I copy the stacks it still says the are not equivalent (stack 1: 2, 3 stack 2: 2, 3).

Comment: @JCPowell OK, you have another bug. I'll update the answer.